# html accordion shows panel-heading not panel-title

Tags: javascript, html

I have this structure in my website:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><strong>Title</strong></a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p> Some collapse info </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I press collpase hyperlink from previous page, next page jumps with panel-body collapsed in top of screen. I want it to jump with panel-title centred on top of the screen. How can I do that?
Javascript code:

```
$(function(){

// check if there is a hash in the url
if ( window.location.hash != '' )
{
    // remove any accordion panels that are showing (they have a class of 'in')
    $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

    // show the panel based on the hash now:
    $(window.location.hash + '.collapse').addClass('in');
}
```

});

When I click in first page on hyperlink item, it throws to the second page and shows 1st image in browsers top position. The thing I wanna do is to show 2nd image in browsers top position. The idea is that I have list with multiple items and when I click in first page, I can't see the title of list, only the body. I need to scroll up a bit to see the title. 
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQL6C.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZbXu.png)

First page

```
<article class="style5">
    <span class="image">
        <img src="pictureOFitem" alt="" />
    </span>
    <a href="SecondPage.html#collapseOne">
        <h2>Info</h2>
    </a>
</article>
```

I mean this by saying "browsers top position" [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gj1g.png)

Comment: Pay attention that your tag ```java``` shuld be ```javascript```. Java != javascript

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: im using only bootstrap. ye sorry about that javascript*

Comment: I don't think that I understand you. Is it a css question- how to make the title centered, or is it js question- how to focus on an element when you enter into the page?

Comment: @KorelK I updated the information to be more clear what I need to get.

Comment: @KasparsLapiņš I don't see any `element` with a `class` of `in`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that sould do the work:

First page:

```
<article class="style5">
    <span class="image">
        <img src="pictureOFitem" alt="" />
    </span>
    <a href="SecondPage.html#title"><!--Pay attention to the id-->
        <h2>Info</h2>
    </a>
</article>
```

Second Page:

```
<div id="title">
    <div id="accordion"><!-- You forgot this one in your post -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-controls="collapseOne"><strong>Title</strong></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p> Some collapse info </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: To auto display the collapse part, you can use in your second page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#title .collapse').addClass('show');
    });
</script>
```

Or with collapse effect:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#title [data-toggle="collapse"]').click();
        },1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For example, in first page I have a list with 20 my most popular services. In second page I have them all as collapsed services- title and the information (information in closed collapse). When I click in first page on any item, I need it to throw to the second page and collapse (open) the right service I choosed with the title on top and information opened. At this moment, when it opens the second page, I see only the collapsed (open) information. The title is a bit above. Like in the Image3, which I added.

Comment: When you redirect by the link to the second page, you redirect to a specific id there, the specific id is what that making that offset from the top of the page. Have you tried my code?

Comment: I have this <div id="accordion">, just forgot to copy it here. The thing is I need to redirect to specific title with opened only that specific "Some collapse info". It works great by setting the collapseOne id in first page. When I try to set this id in title div, it works just as I wanted, but it doesnt open that "Some collapse info".

Comment: your snippet works great, almost as I wanted. It redirects to the second page with specific service on top position in browser, but it didnt open this "Some collapse info". I need it to open it when I click on item in first page.

Comment: I have edited the answer, I think it's all right now :)

Comment: With your update, all second page's services/items are already opened/collapsed and cannot be closed. Something isn't working properly.

Comment: Try the last change in the js part. I changed the select query.